# How to make client know server has finished sending data in C?

Tags: c, linux, udp

I use command line:

echo -e -n "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" | nc -u -s

to mimic client side to test my server program.

The client keeps blocking waiting for server's data. How to make the client side know that server has sent all data and stop blocking.

Here is a clip of my code to send a file content.

```
while(1){
            bzero(buf,MAX);
            fread(buf,MAX,1,fp);
            if(filelen>=MAX){
                sendto(sockfd, buf, MAX, 0,
               (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, cli_len);
               filelen-=MAX;
            }
            else{
                sendto(sockfd, buf, filelen, 0,
               (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, cli_len);
                fclose(fp);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo -e -n "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n" | nc
```

Btw. The HTTP specification says that the server has to close the conection after one request in HTTP/1.0.

PS: Why use UDP for HTTP?

Comment: But how could the client know the server will not send data more? I want the server could receive another request after finished responding the old one. I use sendto() in a while loop to send the whole file content in packets. I use UDP just for practice, I know UDP is not suitable for HTTP.

Comment: When the server closes the connection nc will quit. if you have another question, please ask a new one.